# C# Custom migrations in auto-migration from code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I run all migrations upon start of application like this:

```
            var configuration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
            {
                TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo("DataBase"),
                AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true,
                AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true
            };

            _migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
            _migrator.Update();
```

And have some code-first context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyObject> Objects { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public long Id {get;set;}

    public byte[] Data {get;set;}
}
```

And not used any pregenerated (with EF tools) migrations. At first it was enough, but now I need to run some custom SQL code for database to migrate to latest version. For example, this one:

```
public class MyCustomMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql(@"
            CREATE TABLE Files
            (
                Id BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                Data VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM
            )
        ");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("Files");
    }
}
```

How I can accomplish this task? I tried to set migration directory in configuration, but no success (nothing happens, migration is untouched).

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the built-in migration management via the package manager console?

```
enable-migrations (make sure you have the right project selected - creates a 
                    migrations directory)
add-migration MyFirstMigration
update-database
```

You need to do this manually after every time you change the models in your DbSets on your context. But this way it generates all the migration Sql for you, and creates a Configuration class with a seed method which you can use to update the new schema when you run:

```
update-database
```